# Register a function Handler

Tags: c, signals

I don't know how to do a method with this assignment that has to invoke function `func` when signal `sig` is given as an argument.

```
  void set_sig_handler(int sig,void (*func)(int)){
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [sigaction()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), the handler must have one of the following signatures:

```
/* this one matches your function */
void (*sa_handler)(int);

/* use thhis one If SA_SIGINFO is specified */
void (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
```

Example:

```
#include <signal.h>
....
void set_sig_handler(int sig, void (*func)(int))
{
    struct sigaction act= {0};

    /* set signal handler */
    act.sa_handler = func;

    if (sigaction(sig, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror ("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }
}
```